# Laravel belongsTo not working

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 models in my app, 'User' & 'MedicineType' (each User belongs to one MedicineType).

I made the one-to-many relation between two model using belongsTo() and hasMany(). hasMany() relation works perfectly but belongTo() doesn't work. Does anyone know where did I make a mistake?

> User::find(1)->medicine_type [this returns nothing]
>
> MedicineType::find(1)->users [this returns users]

Here's the code to Models:

```
class MedicineType extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}


class User extends Eloquent {

    public function medicine_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType');
    }
}
```

And here is my database structure:

```
users:
    id
    name
    medicine_type_id 

medicine_types:
    id
    name
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The reason your relation is not working is not because of the relations specified in the model, but because of the method naming in the User model and not specifying the foreign key.

Instead of:

```
public function medicine_type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType');
}
```

Use:

```
public function medicineType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'id');
}
```

I hope this works for you ;)

Everything together:

```
<?php // app/models/MedicineType.php

class MedicineType extends Eloquent {

   // Determines which database table to use
   protected $table = 'medicine_types';

   public function users() 
   {
      return $this->hasMany('User');
   }

}
```

and:

```
<?php // app/models/User.php

class User extends Eloquent {

   // Determines which database table to use
   protected $table = 'users';

   public function medicineType() 
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'id');
   }

}
```

Testing if it works:

```
$user = User::find(1);
return $user->medicineType->name;
```

This successfully returns the related medicine_type's name.

I hope this helps you further ;)

Comment: Nice. Thanks Melvin, this was bugging me as well :)

Comment: thank you so much. i hadn't twigged that the method had to be camel case - no underscores allowed! did i miss this in the docs?

Comment: Melvin, you saved me lots of headaches! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oops.. only wasted an hour! Never think of it, as always start thinking of the complex scenarios first rather than the basics :( Thank you.

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans Why must you specify the foreign key, and isn't the foreign key `medicine_type_id` not `id`

Comment: I agree with @briankip - shouldn't foreign key be `medicine_type_id` and not `id`? The fact that it works with `id` might be just a coincidence with a few records when ids match, but the generated query might be completely wrong joining on `medicine_types.id=users.id` and not `users.medicine_type_id=medicine_types.id`, as it should. I always look into DebugBar to verify if the generated query is right.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe there's an issue with Eloquent finding the foreign key. Try this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function medicine_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'medicine_type_id');
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Also, Eloquent tries to find the table "medicinetypes" and not "medecine_types", so you need to specify that as well using the `$table` variable.

```
class MedicineType extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'medicine_types';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}
```

Comment: @HooK Can you provide some more of your class implementation?

Comment: the "User" class is the laravel default class and it uses the default implements. (implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface)

Comment: @HooK please see my edit. I thought you had specified the table in the MedicineTypes class.

Comment: @HooK well, if you're not getting any errors, then what data do you have in your db that we can check against? when you do find(1), you're just finding the first record in the db. Maybe `User::find(1)->medicine_type` doesn't have a medicine_type in the db.

Comment: I double checked my db, everything seems alright...
For prove here's the return of "MedicineType::find(1)->users;"
[
{
id: 1,
name: "Yashar",
medicine_type_id: 1,
}
]

(The ID of user is 1)

Comment: Hmm....I'll have to look at this later tonight when I get home. I'll try to mockup your setup and see if I can duplicate the issue and get back to you.

Answer (score 4):

I made the stupid mistake of not adding the "return" in the relationship method!

Make sure you return the relationship... Obviously this will **not** work:

```
public function medicineType() 
{
    $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'id');
}
```

It works by adding a return keyword:

```
public function medicineType() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Maybe don't show what doesn't work and show what does work lol....this is just confusing...

Comment: The problem is that it's easy to "gloss over" this code and think you are doing it correctly, like I initially did. I specifically show the right and wrong way to call attention to the fact that it's easy to leave the "return" out and not understand why things are not working.

Answer (score 2):

I change "medicine_type" to "medicineType" and everythings got OK...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the related model's data was deleted & laravel doesn't get soft deleted data in the general query. To get soft deleted data you've to use "withTrashed() or onlyTrashed()".

You can check the documentation here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout#soft-deleting

Answer (score 1):

The number one voted answer might be the best answer in most cases. However, if you still are having trouble loading the related relationship and no luck..

There is one other thing that may work. Take a look at each of the model's tables and their indexes or foreign keys. In my case I had changed the table name but I never updated the involved index and foreign keys.

Solution.

A:(Feeling Lazy) Just delete the associated index or foreign key..

B:(I am not Lazy) Drop table via laravel migration and re-run artisan migrate with the appropriate foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function medicine_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType');
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
$users= App\User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->medicine_type->name;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion