# laravel MyModelClass not found in 1:1 relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `User` and a `Profile` class in my application with 1:1 relationship.
Inside my `ProfileController@show` I can instantiate and build query perfectly fine for each of them but these two lines :

```
$userProfile=$profile->with('user')->where('id',1)->firstOrFail();
$userProfile=$user->with('profile')->where('id',3)->firstOrFail();
```

The first one sends a fatal error Exception with the message: **"Class User Not Found"** and the message for the second one is **"Class Profile Not Found"**

I also tried facades and different way of building query but it didn't work.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469122/laravel-belongsto-not-working) I think there is something wrong with my relationship. I passes the foreign_key explicitly, but it doesn't work.

**Here is some details:**

User class:

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile', 'id');
    }

}
```

Profile class

```
class Profile extends \Eloquent
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
    }
}
```

Database schema:
table "users"

```
id
password
email
username
```

table "profiles"

```
id
user_id
about
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are the classes in an subfolder of models or inside an package ? Why does \Eloquent has an leading backslash? did you do an `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: They are in my namespace like so: `Artronics\User` and `Artronics\Profile` with psr-4 autoloading. yes I tried `composer dump-autoload` actually many times .

Comment: I just tried `php artisan dump-autoload` but still the same result. btw what's the difference between `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan dump-autoload` ?

Comment: the difference is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274082/what-are-differences-between-php-artisan-dump-autoload-and-composer-dump-auto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Model has a namespace you need to insert the full namespaced class as a parameter. Otherwise Eloquent does not know where to find the class.

OR you need to add the models to your classmap in app/config/app.php

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\Path\TO\Model\Profile', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Shouldn't it be a foreign key? http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.html

Comment: Thanks @xjaphx , Since I followed all laravel conventions, actually there is no need to be explicit about foreign keys. btw I tried both `id` and `user_id` and both works! (after inserting full class path)

Comment: @SeyedJalalHosseini While accepted answer solves the namespace for you, this answer is the correct way to define relationship. Your setup 'works', but definitely not how you would expect.

Comment: Yess @xjaphx i checked the doc again. you absolutely right. thanks