# Showing related table information in blade template laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following relationship between my tables

[image: relation]

In my Models i have the following code:

Location Model:

```
public function member() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Member','member_id');
 }
```

Member Model:

```
public function locations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location','member_id');
}
```

Now in my Location controller I created the following function.

```
public function getFinalData(){
    $locations = Location::with('member')->whereNotNull('member_id')->get();
    return view('locations.final-list',['locations'=>$locations]);
}
```

In my blade template however, I am unable to iterate through the member properties

```
<ul>
    @foreach($locations as $location)
      <li>{{$location->id}}</li>
        <li>
         @foreach($location->member as $member)
          {{$member->id}}
         @endforeach
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This gives me the following error:
     **Trying to get property of non-object (View:locations/final-list.blade.php)**

**update:** The result i'm trying to achieve corresponds to this query

```
SELECT locations.location_id,locations.name,members.first_name,          members.last_name , locations.meters
FROM locations,members
WHERE locations.member_id = members.id
```

**Update 2:**

So i tried to access a single location with a single attached to it and that works perfectly

```
public function getFinalData(){
    //$locations = Location::with('member')->whereNotNull('member_id')->get();
    $location = Location::find(0);

    return view('locations.final-list',['location'=>$location]);
}
```

in final-list
$location->member->first_name

**Update 3 **
Tinker Output for one record :
[image]

Comment: member_id is a Pk of members table so how can it be NULL? You have written whereNotNull('member_id').

Comment: @RaviHirani Because I'm getting a list of locations dat have a member_id defined?

Comment: I maybe missing something but your method `getFinalData` seems wrong. When you do a `with` on a model, laravel only fetches the data with respect to that relationship. It doesn't query the associated model. So in your case, when you do this `$locations = Location::with('member')->whereNotNull('member_id')->get();` you should be getting an error `Column not found`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Location model, rewrite below function:-

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'id');
}
```

Get all locations with member detail as below:-

```
$locations = Location::with('member')->get();
```

Hope it will work for you :-)

Comment: The reference on belongsTo needs to stay member_id too, member_id references id on the member table?

Comment: @KrisTemmerman: Yes. see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469122/laravel-belongsto-not-working

Comment: that is not a solution to my issue . @RaviHirani

Comment: I am just trying to say that you have given a wrong reference.

Comment: but with your solution i get the same result @RaviHirani

Comment: @KrisTemmerman I am still surprised to see that same error is coming.  Let me dig into it.

Comment: we can move this over to an appear.in or a team viewer session if that would make it easier for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110223/discussion-between-kristemmerman-and-ravi-hirani).

Comment: did you find time to help me on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For showing related tables information in blade is as shown:

Model Relations
Location Model:

```
public function member() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Member','member_id');
}
```

Member Model:

```
public function locations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location','member_id');
}
```

Get all locations in your controller

```
$locations = Location::all();
return view('locations.final-list', compact('locations'));
```

Or

```
$locations = Location::orderBy('id')->get();
return view('locations.final-list', compact('locations'));
```

Inside your view(blade) write the following code:

```
<div>
    @if($locations)
        @foreach($locations AS $location)
            <div>{{ $location->id }}</div>
            @if($location->member)
                @foreach($location->member AS $member)
                    <div>
                        {{ $member->id }}
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```